# Breaking apart bit patterns, shifting and creating new patterns

Tags: c, bit

As part of a larger problem, I have to take some binary value: 00000000 11011110 (8)

Then, I have to:

1. Derive the bit count in this function - so I've done that by finding the place of the most sig fig.
2. Then store the first 6 numbers of this value into the value 128, such that it equals: 10011110
3. Then store the last 5 numbers of this value into the value 192, such that it equals: 11000011 10011110
4. The two bytes should be stored in some array, buffer[]

I have written this function however, position does not appear to initialise properly in gdb and the values are not outputting correctly. This is my attempt:

```
  void create_value(unsigned short init_val, unsigned char buffer[])
  {
    // get the count
    int position = 0;
    while (init_val >>= 1)
            position++;

    // get total
    int count = position++;

            int start = 128;

            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                    if (((1 << i) & init_val) != 0) start = start | 1 << i;


            buffer[0] = start;

            start = 192;

            for (int i = 7; i < 11; i++) {
                    if (((1 << i) & init_val) !=0) start = start | 1 << i;
            }

            buf[1] = start;
    }
```

Comment: See the edit to my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After

```
while (init_val >>= 1)
        position++;
```

`init_val` will be `0`. When you later use

```
if (((1 << i) & init_val) != 0) start = start | 1 << i;
```

you will never change `start`.

So, after reading through what you're *trying* to do (which is pretty confusingly described), why don't you:

```
void create_value(unsigned short init_value, unsigned char buffer[])
{
    buffer[0] = (init_value & 63) | 128;
    buffer[1] = ((init_value >> 6) & 31) | 192;
    return;
}
```

What this does: `init_value & 63` masks off all but the lowest 6 bits in init_value, as you wanted. The `| 128` then sets the most significant bit of the byte (IFF CHAR_BIT == 8, mind you).
`(init_value >> 6)` shifts init_value down by 6 bits, so now the *original bits 6-11* are *bits 0-4*. `& 31` masks off all bit the lowest 5 bits in this value, `| 192` sets the two most significant bits.

Comment: Okay, so perhaps storing init_val in another variable for the purpose of the later functions will allow me to continue the other operations without losing that value?

Comment: @marchon -- Also note that the second loop is shifting the bits too far.  ORing with (1<<i) will never change start value since `i` starts at 7 (and the 7th bit is already set, and bits 8 through 10 are off the end of the byte).

Comment: @user3386109 That's true, nice catch. I guess I could catch the values that are already filled in in start and start there for the second loop?

Comment: @marchon: Btw, what do you think `int count = position++;` is doing? Looks like it's doing nothing to me.

Comment: If I were writing the code, the first loop would count from 0 to 6 (already does), the second loop would count from 0 to 4 (instead of 7 to 10), and in the the body of the loop, I would check `if (init_val & 1)` and then after the `if`, I would shift `init_val >>= 1`, kind of like the bit counting loop.

Comment: So position is different from the significant bit count. Position returns the index and count is position + 1, and will give me the index plus 1. The weird thing is when I run the values through gdb, position is 538 and increments from there. It's strange because the value is initialized?

Comment: @marchon: Well, 1: `count` will be *less than* `position`, 2: Neither are used in the function past that line.

Comment: Doesn't position start from i of 0, and incrementing it give us the count? The above function gives me exactly one less than the expected count.

Comment: Thanks for the edit - can you describe what the bottom two expressions are doing as it isn't immediately clear. Sorry, quite new to this. Thanks.